# TinyMCE Toolbar CSS inside a Div

Tags: css, html, tinymce, containers, toolbar

i am creating a single TinyMCE toolbar for multiple containers & fixed it at top of all containers area, inside a div wrapper, but i have found that entire CSS of toolbar is lost,after wrapping. It appears like hyperlink urls only. Is there anyway i can apply CSS(Ui.css) link to toolbar inside a  div Or any other workaround

Answer (score 0):

You will need to apply the css to your main page (that is whre your toolbar is located at).